# Google Cloud Video Intelligence Annotate Video node js example

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-speech-api, video-intelligence-api

I just copy and paste from [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/transcription#video_speech_transcription_gcs-nodejs). But somehow, I'm getting typescript error on my code.

[See error message on my code base.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88Qwu.png)

and here is the code example.

```
const videoContext = {
    speechTranscriptionConfig: {
      languageCode: "en-US",
      enableAutomaticPunctuation: true,
    },
  };

  const req = {
    inputUri: gcsUri,
    features: ["SPEECH_TRANSCRIPTION"],
    videoContext: videoContext,
  };

  const [operation] = await client.annotateVideo(req);
  console.log("Waiting for operation to complete...");
  const [operationResult] = await operation.promise();
  // There is only one annotation_result since only
  // one video is processed.
  const annotationResults = operationResult.annotationResults[0];

  for (const speechTranscription of annotationResults.speechTranscriptions) {
    // The number of alternatives for each transcription is limited by
    // SpeechTranscriptionConfig.max_alternatives.
    // Each alternative is a different possible transcription
    // and has its own confidence score.
    for (const alternative of speechTranscription.alternatives) {
      console.log("Alternative level information:");
      console.log(`Transcript: ${alternative.transcript}`);
      console.log(`Confidence: ${alternative.confidence}`);

      console.log("Word level information:");
      for (const wordInfo of alternative.words) {
        const word = wordInfo.word;
        const start_time = wordInfo.startTime.seconds + wordInfo.startTime.nanos * 1e-9;
        const end_time = wordInfo.endTime.seconds + wordInfo.endTime.nanos * 1e-9;
        console.log("\t" + start_time + "s - " + end_time + "s: " + word);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you try ```features: ['SPEECH_TRANSCRIPTION']```,instead of double quotes?

Comment: I also noticed in the code posted you do not have the gcsUri variable declaration is it perhaps missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code but it seems its working on my side:

```
// Imports the Google Cloud Video Intelligence library
const videoIntelligence = require('@google-cloud/video-intelligence');

// Creates a client
const client = new videoIntelligence.VideoIntelligenceServiceClient();

/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following line before running the sample.
 */
const gcsUri = 'gs://nestorbucket/big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb.mp4';

async function analyzeVideoTranscript() {
    const videoContext = {
        speechTranscriptionConfig: {
          languageCode: "en-US",
          enableAutomaticPunctuation: true,
        },
      };
    
      const req = {
        inputUri: gcsUri,
        features: ["SPEECH_TRANSCRIPTION"],
        videoContext: videoContext,
      };
    
      const [operation] = await client.annotateVideo(req);
      console.log("Waiting for operation to complete...");
      const [operationResult] = await operation.promise();
      // There is only one annotation_result since only
      // one video is processed.
      const annotationResults = operationResult.annotationResults[0];
    
      for (const speechTranscription of annotationResults.speechTranscriptions) {
        // The number of alternatives for each transcription is limited by
        // SpeechTranscriptionConfig.max_alternatives.
        // Each alternative is a different possible transcription
        // and has its own confidence score.
        for (const alternative of speechTranscription.alternatives) {
          console.log("Alternative level information:");
          console.log(`Transcript: ${alternative.transcript}`);
          console.log(`Confidence: ${alternative.confidence}`);
    
          console.log("Word level information:");
          for (const wordInfo of alternative.words) {
            const word = wordInfo.word;
            const start_time = wordInfo.startTime.seconds + wordInfo.startTime.nanos * 1e-9;
            const end_time = wordInfo.endTime.seconds + wordInfo.endTime.nanos * 1e-9;
            console.log("\t" + start_time + "s - " + end_time + "s: " + word);
          }
        }
      }
    }


analyzeVideoTranscript();
```

Result: [image]

Can you try check the before you begin section of this [article](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/annotate-video-client-libraries#before-you-begin)?